# First character empty using Ember action on key-press

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When using action on input form like this:

```
  {{input value=firstName action="didType" on="key-press" class="uk-form"}}
```

and controller like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    didType: function(something) {
      console.log("Typed: "+something);

    }
  }
});
```

key presses work, but the first character is undefined. So if I type: "hello" the following outputs: 'Typed: hell'

Anyone know what's wrong?

Here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rejuwosaga/1/).

Comment: I think this is a bug and reported it. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10305

Answer (score 1):

You may bing input controller's property and then use an observer, like this:

```
{{input value=firstname}}
```

then, in JS:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    firstname: '',
    ObserveName: function () {
        console.log('Typed: ' + this.get('firstname'));
    }.observes('firstname').on('init'),
});
```